# ErrorException Undefined index: HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH

Tags: php, android, laravel

```
    if ($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH'] == "your.app.id") {
     //webview
    } else {
      //browser
    }
```

I want to check if the request is from a mobile device or web server. So, I have added this code. But it is giving error

> ErrorException Undefined index: HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH

Comment: I think you should also check that `HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH` is not always exist. You can check it with `!empty()` or `isset()`.

Answer (score 1):

update your script, it work for me

```
if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) && $_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH'] == "your.app.id") {
 //webview
} else {
  //browser
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the problem by 
        if ((strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'], 'Mobile/') !== false) &&               (strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'], 'Safari/') == false) && (strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'], 'iPod/') == false) && (strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'], 'iPhone/') == false) && (strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'], 'iPad/') == false) && (strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'], 'Android/') == false)) {
                //web view
            } else{
                //Mobile view 
            }

Answer (score 0):

This is a Laravel package that utilizes the [Mobile Detect](https://github.com/serbanghita/Mobile-Detect) PHP Class under the hood:

*Mobile_Detect is a lightweight PHP class for detecting mobile devices (including tablets). It uses the User-Agent string combined with specific HTTP headers to detect the mobile environment.*

Nice syntax too:

```
Agent::is('Windows');
Agent::isNexus();
Agent::isMobile();
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved with `if (key_exists('HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH', $_SERVER) && ($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH'] == 'your.app.id')) {`